# Regex: Extract Tweet Username and ID From URL

Tags: php, json, regex, tweets

I'm trying to fetch the tweet URL, if found, in a message with this regex `#^https?://twitter\.com/(?:\#!/)?(\w+)/status(es)?/(\d+)$#is`

But it seems my regex is not correct to fetch for the tweet URL. Below is my full code

```
function gettweet($string)
{
    $regex = '#^https?://twitter\.com/(?:\#!/)?(\w+)/status(es)?/(\d+)$#is';
    $string = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {
        $user = $matches[2];
        $statusid = $matches[3];
        $url = "https://twitter.com/$user/status/$statusid";
        $urlen = urlencode($url);
        $getcon = file_get_contents("https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=$urlen");
        $con = json_decode($getcon, true);
        $tweet_html = $con["html"];
        return $tweet_html;
    }, $string);
    return $string;
}

$message="This is absolutely trending can you also see it here https://twitter.com/itslifeme/status/765268556133064704 i like it";
$mes=gettweet($message);
echo $mes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this wouldn't work as you expect is because you're including the [anchors](http://php.net/regexp.reference.anchors) in your regular expression, which denote that the pattern must match from beginning to end.

By removing the anchors, it matches...

```
$regex  = '#https?://twitter\.com/(?:\#!/)?(\w+)/status(es)?/(\d+)#is';
$string = "This is absolutely trending can you also see it here https://twitter.com/itslifeme/status/765268556133064704 i like it";

if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    var_dump($match);
}
```

The above code gives us...

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(55) "https://twitter.com/itslifeme/status/765268556133064704"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "itslifeme"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(18) "765268556133064704"
}
```

Also, there's really no reason to include the [dot all pattern modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) in your expression.

> **s (`PCRE_DOTALL`)**
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

Comment: Thanks. The regex works perfectly but when i parsed in this, i didn't get any response from the json. $getcon = file_get_contents("https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=$urlen");
$con=json_decode($getcon, true);
$getva=$con["url"];

Comment: Didn't get any response, or `json_decode` is returning null, which [according to the manual](http://php.net/json-decode) indicates failure? Or is it just that `file_get_contents` itself returned `false`, which [according to the manual](http://php.net/file-get-contents) indicates failure? You don't attempt to do any kind of error handling in your code. It's not unusual or unexpected that your code can fail very unexpectedly for you here when you believe it should work flawlessly every single time.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sherif. Please am a php newbie. The json_decode is returning null but the parsed tweet url is valid. Please help me out with the best way to get the perfect results. I want to output the 'html' from the json array and display it as Embedded tweet on my website. Thanks